# After DLL injection - Access to the path "path" is denied

Tags: c++, winapi, hook, dll-injection

I'm trying to write a program that do IAT hooking with dll injection. (The idea is something like EDR that monitor all some winapi calls of some processes)
The pronblem is that after I do the dll injection and switch functions in the IAT table of the process, I try to rebuild my dll project in visual studio and I get "access to the path  is denied". I thought that it's because my dll is still loaded into the process. So I did dll hooking with another dll that switches again the functions in the IAT table from the my functions to the original function. And then, I also did another dll hooking that calls the free library function from the processes and free the first dll.
Maybe I'm missing here somethimg..
This is the function that does the IAT hooking with the dll injection:

```
bool InjectorAndEject::inject(int pid)
{
    printf("\nThe PID of the injceted process is: %d\n", pid);

    // Get process handle passing in the process ID.
    HANDLE process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);
    if (!process) {
        printf("Error: the specified process couldn't be found.\n");
        return false;
    }

    // Get address of the LoadLibrary function.
    LPVOID addr = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
    if (!addr) {
        printf("Error: the LoadLibraryA function was not found inside kernel32.dll library.\n");
        return false;
    }

    // Allocate new memory region inside the process's address space.
    LPVOID arg = (LPVOID)VirtualAllocEx(process, NULL, strlen(this->_bufferToHook) + 1, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (!arg) {
        printf("Error: the memory could not be allocated inside the chosen process.\n");
        return false;
    }
    // Write the argument to LoadLibraryA to the process's newly allocated memory region. 
    int n = WriteProcessMemory(process, arg, this->_bufferToHook, strlen(this->_bufferToHook) + 1, NULL);
    if (!n) {
        printf("Error: there was no bytes written to the process's address space.\n");
        return false;
    }

    // Inject our DLL into the process's address space.
    HANDLE threadID = CreateRemoteThread(process, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)addr, arg, NULL, NULL);
    CloseHandle(process);
    if (!threadID) {
        printf("Error: the remote thread could not be created.\n");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        printf("Success: the remote thread was successfully created.\n");
        return true;
    }
}
```

The function (reutrnOriginalFunctions) that returns the functions I switched in the IAT hooking to the original functions is the same like above except that it loads other dll.

This is the function that free the first dll:

```
bool InjectorAndEject::eject(int pid)
{
    this->reutrnOriginalFunctions(pid);
    // We open the process and gets handle to our dll
    HANDLE process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);
    HMODULE tempHM = LoadLibraryA("myDLL\\x64\\Debug\\myDLL.dll");
    // We get address in the injected process of the free library
    LPVOID addr = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll"), "FreeLibrary");
    if (!addr) 
    {
        std::cout << "Error: the freeLibraryA function was not found inside kernel32.dll library." << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    // We call the free library function to free our dll
    HANDLE threadID = CreateRemoteThread(process, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)addr, tempHM, NULL, NULL);
    if (!threadID) 
    {
        printf("Error: the remote thread could not be created.\n");
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Success: the remote thread was successfully created.\n");
        return true;
    }
}
```

As I said, the problem is that if I try to rebuild the first dll after the injection and the uninjection, I get the error message above..

Comment: Make sure that the original DLL is no longer in use, when you're trying to compile a new version.

Comment: You can't overwrite a .dll as long as it is loaded in a process.  In other words, your InjectorAndEject::eject() function does not work.  tempHM is not likely to have the correct value since you loaded the dll into your process, not the victim process.  A workaround of sorts is to use the linker's /BASE option to give it a unique load address.

Answer (score 0):

As *[Three Ways to Inject Your Code into Another Process](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4610/Three-Ways-to-Inject-Your-Code-into-Another-Proces#section_2)* said,

> 6. Retrieve the exit code of the remote thread (GetExitCodeThread). Note that this is the value returned by LoadLibrary, thus the base
>    address (HMODULE) of our mapped DLL.
> 7. Free the memory allocated in Step #2 (VirtualFreeEx).
> 8. Unload the DLL from the remote process via CreateRemoteThread & FreeLibrary. Pass the HMODULE handle retreived in Step #6 to
>    FreeLibrary (via lpParameter in CreateRemoteThread). Note: If your
>    injected DLL spawns any new threads, be sure they are all terminated
>    before unloading it.

**Disclaimer**:
This response contains a reference to a third party World Wide Web site. Microsoft is providing this information as a convenience to you. Microsoft does not control these sites and has not tested any software or information found on these sites; therefore, Microsoft cannot make any representations regarding the quality, safety, or suitability of any software or information found there. There are inherent dangers in the use of any software found on the Internet, and Microsoft cautions you to make sure that you completely understand the risk before retrieving any software from the Internet.

Comment: Please provide a reference when reproducing content published elsewhere.

Comment: @IInspectable For a few criteria. Just search the italic portion.

Comment: Discovering the source isn't something you can delegate to readers. It's a requirement for the author reproducing text to disclose its source.

Comment: *"Microsoft is providing this information"* - I don't see how that were to be accurate.

Comment: @יהב The address returned by `LoadLibrary` in the current process is meaningless to the other processes. But the exit code of the remote thread which runs `LoadLibrary` is the correct base address (HMODULE) of the mapped DLL. Any update?