# SetWindowsHookExW not calling the MouseProc callback procedure

Tags: c, winapi, mouse-hook

So I'm trying to run a simple code in C that prints the position of the mouse every time it moves. To keep the program running for a while and then exit, I use a for loop shown below. I want the hook to be associated with the current thread only.
Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

// Global hook handle
HHOOK hHook = NULL;

// Mouse hook callback
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    printf("Entered\n");

    if (nCode >= 0) {
        if ((nCode == HC_ACTION) && (wParam == WM_MOUSEMOVE)) {
            MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT* pMouseStruct = (MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
            printf("Mouse X: %ld, Mouse Y: %ld\n", pMouseStruct->pt.x, pMouseStruct->pt.y);
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main() {
    // Install the mouse hook
    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE, (HOOKPROC) &MouseHookProc, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());

    if (hHook == NULL) {
        printf("Hook installation failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Keep program running (edit 1)
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    // Unhook and exit
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
    return 0;
}
```

The printf statement never gets executed. Why is the proc not getting called even though the hook was set up successfully?

Edit: My apologies for not mentioning this explicitly but I had initially tried it with a message loop instead of the `for` loop shown above, but the result was the same. It does however, work if I use a low level mouse hook `WH_MOUSE_LL` instead. Why is this happening?

*Update:* I'll try to describe what I'm trying to achieve better. Firstly, I'm trying to make a standalone console executable, not a Windows app. I was initially trying to poll the mouse position a finite number of times but now I believe a better approach for my application would be to sample as long as the program is active, and then release the hooks along with with the other cleanup jobs to exit the program gracefully. The problem I'm facing is that I'm unable to use a normal mouse hook `WM_MOUSE` as opposed to a low-level one `WM_MOUSE_LL`. I read from some sources that the hook procedure must be injected into the executable through a DLL but I can't get that to work either. Right now the only thing that works is a low-level mouse hook which slows down my program and makes it almost unusable.

Comment: you have no message loop. hook called inside GetMessage/PeekMessage. but you not call this api. as result and hook will be not called

Comment: This is explicitly spelled out in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/mouseproc#remarks): *"This hook may be called in the context of the thread that installed it. The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook. **Therefore, the thread that installed the hook must have a message loop.**"*

Comment: @IInspectable that should be posted as an answer instead of a comment

Comment: @RemyLebeau How would that be useful as an answer? It's the question that's completely bonkers. Telling them how they could receive hook callbacks isn't useful when their thread of interest won't ever trigger those hook events.

Comment: It doesn't work even with a message loop. It does work with a low level mouse hook `WH_MOUSE_LL` but not if I try to associate the hook with the current thread using a normal mouse hook.

Comment: A console application doesn't receive mouse input messages. Installing a `WH_MOUSE` hook for the primary thread of a console application is a rather costly no-op. You will need to explain what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @IInspectable Can I make another thread and add the hook to that for periodic measurements?

Comment: Nothing is holding you back from doing so, but that won't magically change the outcome. You're still not receiving any mouse input messages on that thread. As I wrote in the previous comment: You will need to explain what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Try the document sample [Monitoring System Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-hooks#monitoring-system-events).

Comment: @IInspectable So I am trying to poll the mouse position in parallel with my program execution. I am trying to make a keystream generator and asynchronously add the position of the cursor to a randomness buffer. I need to stop polling and release the hook once a certain number (say 100) of distinct positions have been recorded.

Comment: Referring to my previous comment, this is why I can't just have a message loop hindering program execution since I am trying to achieve asynchrony with the mouse polling.

Comment: In other words, you are trying to sample a finite number of global mouse positions from a console application. If you update the question with this problem statement, I can try to provide an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in comments, you need a Win32 message loop to be able to receive `WH_MOUSE` hook events.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/mouseproc

> This hook may be called in the context of the thread that installed it. The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook. **Therefore, the thread that installed the hook must have a message loop.**

Sample (main.cpp):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

static HHOOK p_hook = nullptr;

BOOL WINAPI HandlerRoutine(_In_ DWORD dwCtrlType);
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelMouseProc(_In_ int nCode, _In_ WPARAM wParam, _In_ LPARAM lParam);

int main()
{
    if (SetConsoleCtrlHandler(HandlerRoutine, TRUE) == 0)
        return ~0;

    p_hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, LowLevelMouseProc, nullptr, 0);
    if (p_hook == nullptr)
        return ~0;

    MSG msg = { 0 };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    if (p_hook != nullptr)
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(p_hook);

    return static_cast<int>(msg.wParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelMouseProc(_In_ int nCode, _In_ WPARAM wParam, _In_ LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        auto m_struct = reinterpret_cast<MSLLHOOKSTRUCT*>(lParam);
        std::cout << "x: " << m_struct->pt.x << " y: " << m_struct->pt.y << std::endl;
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(p_hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

BOOL WINAPI HandlerRoutine(_In_ DWORD dwCtrlType)
{
    if (dwCtrlType == CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT || dwCtrlType == CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT)
    {
        if (UnhookWindowsHookEx(p_hook) == TRUE)
            p_hook = nullptr;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Note that the OP is using a `WH_MOUSE` hook, but your example is using a `WH_MOUSE_LL` hook instead. Different semantics, but the same message loop requirement does exist for both.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77293436/setwindowshookexw-not-calling-the-mouseproc-callback-procedure#comment136288184_77293436), `WH_MOUSE` absolutely definitely works fine.

Using the [Monitoring System Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-hooks#monitoring-system-events) document sample.

[image]

> I need to stop polling and release the hook once a certain number (say
> 100) of distinct positions have been recorded.

Use [UnhookWindowsHookEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-unhookwindowshookex).

Comment: Refering to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134183/understanding-the-low-level-mouse-and-keyboard-hook-win32), seems like the MouseProc callback must be in a dll whereas the message loop and SetWindowsHookEx must be in an exe.

Comment: Why not refer to [MouseProc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/mouseproc#remarks) and [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77319626/how-can-i-catch-a-keybind-like-f6-no-matter-what-is-in-focus-with-c)

Comment: The OP is writing a console application. You've changed the problem by switching from `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` to `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`. As such, this contribution addresses a problem that's distinctly different from the problem statement in the question. Deletion is strongly encouraged.

Comment: @vibhav950 with the third program, if you don't like the global hook, a DLL injected to the third program is the way. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75680011/15511041 for a sample.